# Запуск cron'a через скрипт php

Tags: php, cron

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Нужно выполнять асинхронно php скрипт, в котором несколько команд sleep с последующей отправкой сообщений в telegram. Пришел к выводу, что на данный момент лучшим решением было бы через php запускать cron, который асинхронно запускает скрипт с входящими get-параметрами. На моем хостинге я могу вручную запускать мгновенно исполняющиеся задания крона:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь же мне нужен код, который я вставлю в php-скрипт, чтобы он запускал также одноразовое задание cron, которое и запустит php-скрипт в том самом нужном мне асинхронном режиме.
Добавлю, что нужно передать лишь один(например сериализованный) массив параметров, в котором значения каждый раз разные и отправляются из скрипта, в котором и запускается задание cron'a.

Comment: Много таких задач для cron? Вручную никак нельзя добавить чтоли?

Comment: Фишка была в том, что скрипт вызывался тот же, но с разными параметрами. Но нужна была именно асинхронность)

Comment: Представьте себе скрипт, который запускается, ждет sleep'ом 30 секунд, отправляет в telegram сообщение, потом ждет еще 30 секунд, проверяет данные в базе данных, изменяет их, из них формирует и отправляет второе сообщение telegram. При этом могут податься сразу 2 заявки на выполнение скрипта, в итоге вторая заявка ждет минуту, пока выполнится первая заявка на выполнение скрипта, это мне и нужно как раз обойти.

Comment: асинхронность достигается многими методами, но про использование crontab для этих целей я бы никогда не подумал.

Answer (score 0):

Сложная задумка конечно.... может просто, если нет необходимости отслеживать что и как там выполняется.

```
exec("php /path/my_script.php param1=q param2=a");
```

Либо если разбирать стандартный поток вывода

```
$stdout = popen('my-command --inputargument1 a', 'r');
```

Comment: В обоих случаях достигается асинхронный запуск скриптов? На хосте узнал от тп, что такое провернуть не получится(vps нужен), жаль конечно, но все равно интересно на будущее, возможно ли такое вообще было реализовать. Суть в том, что скрипт должен выполняться именно минуту, фиксировать изменения в базе данных и в зависимости от них уже отправлять сообщения в telegram api, нужно чтобы он именно выполнялся в реальном времени. Скорей всего для таких целей подошел бы node.js, но на виртуальном хосте я точно навряд ли его смогу подключить, да и не знаю его))

Comment: В итоге похоже придется создавать cron-задание через панель на ежеминутную проверку данных из бд, а это немного не то, что я хотел. Во-первых будет кушать лишнюю нагрузку, ибо каждую минуту проверять данные из бд - такое, учитывая, что этот скрипт будет на первых порах не так часто вызываться. Мне просто нужно независимое выполнение скрипта(без очереди), даже если не через cron, ибо в текущих реалиях php просто ждет пока выполнится первый скрипт.